# Bogus Value left behind in ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a ComboBox which uses Dropdown as the ComboBoxStyle. We want the user to have the flexibility of being able to actually type any text they want in the box and hence are not using DropDownList which limits what can be typed.

The problem we have is, if the user types a value "abc" which does not exist in the list and tabs away, the bogus value is left behind. The user tends to believe that the wrong value that has been typed actually exists in the list.

Eventually after form submission this value is not applied.

Is there any way I can tab away from the ComboBox but not have the false value left behind?

Comment: there should be an OnBlur-event that's triggered when the control loses focus.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I don't have any JavaScript in my application. Its all System Windows Forms

Comment: Windows Forms-controls _have events, too_. i suggest reading the manual. plus: i never said anything about javascript. where did you get javascript from?

Comment: you can use the [Validating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.validating?view=netcore-3.1) event or the [LostFocus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.combobox.lostfocus) event. There you can validate the input. Please read the "Remarks" section in the "Validating" article. There is the order of events written down when a control looses focus (or in your words: "when you tab away").